# Trying to get property 'id_dimensiona' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

i get error Trying to get property 'id_dimensiona' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\includes\forms\machinedecoupe.php on line 198
PHP 7.4 MariaDB 10.4.22

function 1

`

```
public static function find_by_id($id){ 
    global $database;
    
    $array_result=static::exec_query("SELECT * FROM ".static::$db_table." WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1");
    //Example : SELECT * FROM dimension WHERE id=669 LIMIT 1

    return  !empty($array_result) ? array_shift($array_result) : false;
}
```

`

function 2 :

`

```
foreach ($dims as $dim) {

     if(Lignedecoupe::find_by_dim_count($dim->id_dim,$dim->id_decoupe)!=0)
 { 
 
  $obj =  Dimension::find_by_id($dim->id_dim);
  echo print_r($obj->id_dimensiona); //error here showing data and error

 

  echo '   <tr >
        <td class="col-md-6">'.Dimensiona::find_by_id(Dimension::find_by_id($dim->id_dim)->id_dimensiona)->ValeurA.'*'.Dimensionb::find_by_id(Dimension::find_by_id($dim->id_dim)->id_dimensionb)->ValeurB.'*'.Dimensionc::find_by_id(Dimension::find_by_id($dim->id_dim)->id_dimensionc)->ValeurC.'</td>
        <td class="col-md-8">'.Decoupe::find_by_id($dim->id_decoupe)->type_decoupe.'</td> 
  
         <td class="col-md-12"><input  class="col-md-14" type="number" min="0" name='.$k.' id='.$k.' value='.Lignedecoupe::find_by_dim_count($dim->id_dim,$dim->id_decoupe).'></input>
       </td>
           
  
        '.$message3[$k].'
   </tr> ';

 }
```

`

i get error Trying to get property 'id_dimensiona' of non-object in

print_r

```
Dimension Object ( [id] => 669 [id_dimensiona] => 2 [id_dimensionb] => 2 [id_dimensionc] => 4 ) 1 Dimension Object ( [id] => 624 [id_dimensiona] => 2 [id_dimensionb] => 2 [id_dimensionc] => 1 ) 1 Dimension Object ( [id] => 1 [id_dimensiona] => 1 [id_dimensionb] => 1 [id_dimensionc] => 1 ) 1 Dimension Object ( [id] => 768 [id_dimensiona] => 2 [id_dimensionb] => 5 [id_dimensionc] => 10 ) 1 Dimension Object ( [id] => 661 [id_dimensiona] => 3 [id_dimensionb] => 4 [id_dimensionc] => 3 ) 1 1
```

Notice: Trying to get property 'id_dimensiona' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\includes\forms\machinedecoupe.php on line 204

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump($obj)` or a `dd(gettype($obj))` and show what it returns? Most probably it returns an array.

Comment: Dimension Object ( [id] => 669 [id_dimensiona] => 2 [id_dimensionb] => 2 [id_dimensionc] => 4 ) 1

Comment: What about `dd(gettype($obj))`?

Comment: @NAwfalNieme Maybe, but I think you didn't dump the right `$obj`. Did you dump all? One of them is probably `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Syscall pointed out, the error might have been triggered due to the `false` being returned.

Try wrapping your code like this:

```
  $obj =  Dimension::find_by_id($dim->id_dim);
  if(is_object($obj)){
    echo print_r($obj->id_dimensiona); //error here showing data and error
  }
```

Furthermore, if you want to handle if in case the output is not an object, attach an else statement as well.

```
if(is_object($obj)){
    echo print_r($obj->id_dimensiona); //error here showing data and error
  }
else{
  echo $obj;
}
```